# Get the height of each row while using JqueryUI sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am using JqueryUI sortable so that I can sort and rearrange blocks. I am trying to get all the heights to equalize to the max height per row given that I do not know the height of each block and that they are constantly changing (because they are sortable). How do I get the max height of each row?

Here is an example that I am working with: http://jsfiddle.net/zrNNZ/40/

I am using inline-blocks. Here is the CSS:

```
.blocks {
padding: 0px;
border: 0px;
margin: 0px;
display: inline-block;
font-size:0px;
width: 600px;
}

.block {
opacity: 1.0;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
position:relative;
padding: 0px;
border: 0px;
margin-right: 2px;
margin-bottom: 2px;
border-spacing: 0px;
};
```

As you can see in the example each block starting on the next row naturally accommodates for the max height of the previous row. Rather than having a lot of empty space between smaller blocks and larger blocks I want the max height of the row so that I can stretch the smaller blocks so that each row has the same height. The max height of each row can vary, I just want all the heights to be same all the way across.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help you, let me know if you have any questions..  I am using the stop event and looking for when block left position is `0` so that I know its a new row.

```
stop: function(event, ui){
    //alert('stopped'); 
    var row = 0;
    var maxheight = 0;
    $('.block').each(function(){
        if($(this).position().left == 0){
            if(row > 0)
                alert('Row ' + row + ' max-height: ' + maxheight);
            row++;
            maxheight = $(this).height(); 
        }
        else {
            if(maxheight < $(this).height())
                maxheight = $(this).height();
        }
    });
    if(row > 1)
        alert('Row ' + row + ' max-height: ' + maxheight);
}
```

Here is a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/zrNNZ/43/

Comment: @RosesAreRed please mark this answer as accepted if it answered your question, otherwise give feedback on what is not resolved. Thanks